# How to use external javascript code in an app with multiple components

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angular

I'm very new to angular2 and javascript but I have an example running in javascript using this example found in the d3 home page:

http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6

Which I've tested in my normal "project" (I'm using eclipse with Nodeclipse plugin), and it works, I can see the circles and so on.

Now I do not fully comprehend how to add this functionality to an angular project, closer I have got is by doing something like:

```
<script>
      System.import('app/liquidFillGauge.js');
  </script>
```

and then in the "app" I want to have multiple components so I can display that JS code in a certain place or formatted or whatever and then being able to display more stuff on the web, such as maps or buttons or whatever. But it does not work, it simply displays the "hole" where the circles would be, it's empty and shows no functionality, no color, nothing. So I believe the css aspect is working but not the functionality given by the js itself.

I'm sorry for my poor vocabulary but right now I don't really have the knowledge to call certain aspects/functionality by its name, that being said I'm trying to read as much documentation as I can, from the main page of angular2 and blogs I see when looking for info.

So what I want to know is what the approach would be, both with the import mechanism and with the idea of having external libraries/resources that I then use with angular.

Comment: You should add code that demonstrates what you have tried. Ideally a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co) or similar where the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: thing is, I wanted to learn this in an abstract way, not just patch what I've got, not sure how the approach for that is tbh

Comment: StackOverflow is for concrete programming problems not for discussing general ideas. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: just checked again the dont ask, I had already looked at it, I do not think the question is generic nor a what you like to use type of question, nor it is subjective, I'm asking how something is done. I want to know how something is done, in angular, using javascript, since almost every example out there uses typescript